# How to have dynamic property values in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, dynamic, properties

I have a property file in my node app  with the content as
**propertyFiles = dev.property**

Is there any way I can have dynamic values for property value so that I can have the property file name formed with the current environment like below and access this property in code.

**propertyFiles = {process.env.ENV}.property**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use environment variables which are stored in a .env file, you will first need to install dotenv and @types/dotenv :

`npm install dotenv`

`npm install --save-dev @types/dotenv`

Then you can access all your variables using `process.env.MY_VAR`